# Join two timelines / list of tuples

Tags: python

I have timelines/timeseries which consist of a list of two-tuples where the first part of the tuple is a timestamp and the second part is the value. The tuples are ordered by their timestamp.

I now have two of these timelines and need to divide them by each other. This means that if I got values in both timelines for the same timestamp, I need to divide them. If there is no value in one of the timelines on the timestamp, 0 should be assumed. If (and only if) a division by zero occurs, NaN should be assumed. The timestamps have large gaps, which means that iterating from min(timestamp) to max(timestamp) is not a solution.

I constructed a solution which is both, very unpythonic and has a poor running time. As the timelines are about a million entries long, performance is important for me. My solution does not take advantage, that both lists are sorted.

Is there a better solution, if yes which?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

l1 = [(1, 100), (2, 1000),           (4, 1500), (5, 5400),          (7, 7800)]
l2 = [(1, 20),  (2, 400),  (3, 240), (4, 500),  (5, 100),  (6, 27),          ]
ex = [(1, 5),   (2, 2),    (3, 0),   (4, 3),    (5, 54),   (6, 0),  (7, float('NaN'))]

def f(l1, l2):
  #Turn to dicts:
  l1d = dict(l1)
  l2d = dict(l2)

  #Compute Keyspace
  keys = set(l1d.keys()).union(set(l2d.keys()))

  result = []
  for key in keys:
    if not key in l2d:
      result.append((key, float('NaN')))
    elif key not in l1d:
      result.append((key, 0))
    else:
      result.append((key, l1d[key]/l2d[key])) 

  return result

r = f(l1, l2)

print("L1: %s" % (l1))
print("L2: %s" % (l2))
print("")
print("Expected: %s" % (ex))
print("Result: %s" % (r))
```

Comment: which python version?

Comment: lets say 2.7, but I'm willing to switch to 3 for performance.

Comment: You could reuse the fact that the list are sorted and iterate one step at a time. Not quite sure what the pythonic way to write this would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is needed, have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = [(1, 100), (2, 1000),           (4, 1500), (5, 5400),          (7, 7800)]
l2 = [(1, 20),  (2, 400),  (3, 240), (4, 500),  (5, 100),  (6, 27),          ]

s1 = pd.Series(dict(l1))
s2 = pd.Series(dict(l2))
```

now a very explicit mathematical operation:

```
s1 / s2
```

returns

```
1     5.0
2     2.5
3     NaN
4     3.0
5    54.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
```

If you want to replace `NaN` with zeroes if present in `l2`:

```
s1.reindex(s1.index|s2.index).fillna(0) / s2


1     5.0
2     2.5
3     0.0
4     3.0
5    54.0
6     0.0
7     NaN
```

Works perfectly well for million entries as well. You can use datetimes in index and operate on them datetimecally.

Comment: Thanks! I need to distinguish between 0 and NaN: 0 for missing in the first set, and NaN for the second set. I'll update my question.